# order of a record in oracle

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to find, in oracle, which record was entered first, which second, and so on?  This is not necessarily the SCN of the record, since I don't care about the exact time.  I just want to order the records by the order in which they were entered.

Comment: You might end up finding some _trick_ to achieve your purpose. *But* in the general case, you definitively should consider the table content as an *unordered set*. If you need to retrieve rows in some particular order, you have to provide the necessary informations as part of _your_ data. Eventually it could be automatically generated "behind the scene" (using a `sequence` for ex.).

Comment: As a good practice, always have two `DATE` columns. One for `DDL` changes and another for `DML` changes.

Answer (score 2):

In general, not unless you have some column that provides that information (e.g. `create_date`).

If you can assume that rows are never updated and your table was built with `ROWDEPENDENCIES`, you could order by the `ORA_ROWSCN`.  But it's pretty rare that you would have such a table so that's not a particularly useful answer in general.

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge, but couldn't it be possible to infer the order of row insertion from their _physical_ location as returned by [`ROWID`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - No.  `ROWID` values can be reused for different rows, the `ROWID` for a single row can change over time, and the `ROWID` of rows in extents allocated later may be earlier than the `ROWID` of rows allocated earlier.  The `ROWID` may work in some very limited situations-- no deletes, no updates, all data in a single extent, etc. but that's even less likely than the `ORA_ROWSCN` to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

During all my years with Oracle, I have trusted more on my own developed logic and coding practices. In this particular scenario, rather than (ab)using the database, it would be a good practice, to have two `DATE` columns. One for `DDL` changes and another for `DML` changes.

I usually name the `COLUMNS` as `DT_TM_STAMP` and `DT_TM_STAMP_CRTE` for `DML` and `DDL` changes respectively. The datetimestamp create column is not going to change that frequently as compared to the datetimestamp column. Since, we all expect `DML` activity to be more than `DDL` . At any moment, if we want to know when was a particular record `inserted`, `updated` or `deleted`, all we need to do is look for the datetimestamp column.

**Update** I was not clear with my explanation about the two datetime columns. Thanks to Jeffrey Kemp to point it out that all I was talking about was *DML* and not *DDL*.

**Test case**

There are two columns, `dt_tm_stamp_crte` to store the datetime of insertion of row, and `dt_tm_stamp` to keeep a track of all DML changes to the row. So, the first time when a row is inserted, both the columns would have same datetime, however, from next DML operation, only the `dt_tm_stamp` column would be updated with current datetime.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> DROP TABLE t;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT * FROM emp WHERE 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD (dt_tm_stamp DATE, dt_tm_stamp_crte DATE);

Table altered.

SQL> INSERT INTO t SELECT e.*, SYSDATE, SYSDATE FROM emp e;

14 rows created.

SQL> SELECT ename, dt_tm_stamp, dt_tm_stamp_crte FROM t;

ENAME      DT_TM_STAMP         DT_TM_STAMP_CRTE
---------- ------------------- -------------------
SMITH      10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
ALLEN      10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
WARD       10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
JONES      10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
MARTIN     10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
BLAKE      10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
CLARK      10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
SCOTT      10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
KING       10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
TURNER     10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
ADAMS      10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
JAMES      10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
FORD       10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53
MILLER     10/10/2014 13:19:53 10/10/2014 13:19:53

14 rows selected.

SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_LOCK.sleep(10);
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> UPDATE t SET ename = 'LALIT', dt_tm_stamp = SYSDATE WHERE ename = 'SCOTT';

1 row updated.

SQL> SELECT ename, dt_tm_stamp, dt_tm_stamp_crte FROM t WHERE ename = 'LALIT';

ENAME      DT_TM_STAMP         DT_TM_STAMP_CRTE
---------- ------------------- -------------------
LALIT      10/10/2014 13:20:03 10/10/2014 13:19:53

SQL>
```

The `dt_tm_stamp` column update could be done via `TRIGGER`. I have just demonstrated the significance of the columns, how to achieve it is up to the developer.

Comment: What do you mean by "DDL changes" and how does that relate to a date/time column?

Comment: In addition to DML changes, the table might have modifications like addition of a new column etc. Thus, this additional datetime create column can keep track of that. It was just an additional suggestion.

Comment: but that doesn't make sense. Any DDL (such as adding a column) by definition affects the *entire table* - so it's going to be the same datetime value on every single record anyway.

Comment: You missed my point, I said two different columns for DML and DDL. So, DML operations will keep modifying the dt_tm_stamp of the rows whcih are effected, but DDL operations would modify the dt_tm_stamp_crte column. Yes, of course, all the rows will have the same datetime since DDL effects entire table. It would keep a track of DDL changes too, easy to track and maintain.

Comment: No, I didn't miss your point, what I don't get is the utility of storing the *exact same date/time* on *every single record* in the table. If I'm going to waste that much storage space there's gotta be some use case for which that data is useful.

Comment: But the same column can also be used to store when a row was created. So, first time both columns for a row would be same, however, from next DML changes, only dt_tm_stamp will keep updating , and the dt_tm_stamp_crte would remain as it is to signify when the row was originally created. Hope it makes sense now. Perhaps, I should add a test case to demonstrate what I am saying.

Comment: *"I usually name the COLUMNS as DT_TM_STAMP and DT_TM_STAMP_CRTE for DML and DDL changes respectively."* You said dt_tm_stamp_crte was for the last *DDL* change, not the time when the row was inserted. Inserting (creating) a record is done by *DML*, not DDL.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I got confused myself while explaining the significance of dt_tm_stamp_crte column. it would store only the creation date, i.e. datetime of insertion of row. DDL datetime not required as another column. I will clarify that with a test case in my answer. Thanks for pointing out my confusion.

Comment: Thanks again for finding the mistake, I have added an update in my answer.